Havan without initiation?
I was seeing few articles about Navarātri. Where author has given detailed steps for mantra Japa with havan details.
As per my knowledge from this community (with scripture references)

No mantra shall be chanted without Diksha.
Only Nama japa is eligible without initiation.

Does havan requires initiation? Suppose if some one is doing havan with naama(e.g 108 stotras)?

correct. Mantra initiation is required. [These days everyone are "equal" though not in knowledge; hence whatever those who learned do, others also want to do...They do it, very badly and with evil consequences.]
